# postgresql, insert several sets of 3 items with 2 same item in every set

Tags: postgresql

I need to insert several sets of 3 items. 2 items are the same in every set.
I want to put at position of $1 this clause: EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM NOW() AT TIME ZONE 'UTC')

```
WITH data(serial_id, banned_ts, reason) AS (
    VALUES (x, $1, $2),(y, $1, $2),(z, $1, $2)
    )
    INSERT INTO _serial_ids_banned (serial_id, banned_ts, reason)
    SELECT d.serial_id, d.banned_ts, d.reason
    FROM data d
    WHERE NOT EXISTS
        (SELECT 1 FROM _serial_ids_banned b
        WHERE b.serial_id = d.serial_id);
```

If I do it then the clause will be evaluated 3 times(or more depending on number of the sets). Is it possible to create such a query that will evaluate the clause only once and use it in every set?

Comment: `WITH data(serial_id, banned_ts, reason) AS (SELECT unnest(array[x,y,z]), $1, $2)` for example.

Comment: Abelisto, thanks! Great trick! Very clear.

Answer (score 1):

or with explicit join:

```
t=# prepare so1(text,text) as
with p(banned_ts, reason) as (values ($1,$2))
, sid(serial_id) as (values('x'),('y'),('z'))
, data as (select * from sid join p on true)
select * from data;
PREPARE
t=# execute so1('a','b');
 serial_id | banned_ts | reason
-----------+-----------+--------
 x         | a         | b
 y         | a         | b
 z         | a         | b
(3 rows)
```